# ExitCode of RunProgramInGuest in Jenkins job

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I'm running a batch file in virtual machine by jenkins job. I using following command to run it.

```
..path..\vmrun.exe -T ws -gu username -gp password runProgramInGuest "c:\vm_image.vmx" -activeWindow -interactive "C:\Installer.bat"
```

The job is running correctly and installing software (by run batch file).
But sometime it is exiting with exit code 2.
So jenkins is showing as job failed.

Shall I know what is the exit code 2 mean in this job?
What are other possible exit code for this command and there meanings?

How shall I find whether job passed or failed?

Comment: Did you look here? 
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix110_reference/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you ran, it's:

0 – VIX_OK
The operation was successful.

1 – VIX_E_FAIL
Unknown error.

2 – VIX_E_OUT_OF_MEMORY
Memory allocation failed: out of memory.